# How to change a url that uses a #id to a specific spot in the page, into something else

Tags: php, http, url

I have a link  that  uses an id from a div to go to a different spot in the website (in index.php) so the link displayed is 
www.mysite.net/something/something2/#test

And the #id is a simple div with id=test in the index.php

Is there a way to make the displayed URL like this?
www.mysite.net/something/something2/

I have read some similar issues and most of the replies recommended to use the htaccess file, however, I don't understand how I should do that

Comment: URL fragments (`#whatever`) aren't sent to the server so there's nothing you can do with them through .htaccess or PHP.

Comment: So since i am using a div in the index like in the middle of my page, it will be shown as www.mysite.net/something/something2/#test

Comment: I think you can use cookie to acheive your requirement, On click you can set cookies using javascript and read cookie value when page loads. It will work only if you are navigating to www.mysite.net/something/something2/#test  using click

Comment: hmm i will try that then. Thank you very much

Comment: _“So since i am using a div in the index like in the middle of my page, it will be shown as www.mysite.net/something/something2/#test”_ - and what is the _problem_ with that? If any user wanted to bookmark the page with it actually “pointing” to that position or share the link with someone, then `#test` _should_ be in the address bar, otherwise where are they supposed to get that value from? This sounds like you are trying to “fix” a problem that isn’t actually one, resp. are misguided by some wrong “aesthetic” desire here.

Comment: Its not a problem since it is working fine. I was asked to find a way that the #test is not displayed for SEO reasons and not for "aesthetic" ones.